# Value of a continuous function at a point

Tags: calculus

Let $x(t)$  is a  continuous function defined from $[0,\infty )$ to $[0, \infty)$ and $x(0) = 0$.
If $(x(t))^2 \le 2 + \int_{0}^t ( x(s)ds ,  \forall t\ge 0 $, then $x( \sqrt2)$ belongs to

- $[0,2]$
- $[0,\frac{3}{\sqrt 2} ]$
- $[10,\infty ) $

First I took $x(t) = 0,  \forall t \ge 0 $, then obviously $x( \sqrt 2) $ doesn't belong to the last interval, so it is out.
Now among the remaining 2 inervals I have to find the answer.

Any insight. Thank you

Comment: If the first answer is true then so is the second.  So, **if** only one answer is true then it must be the second.

Comment: Only one option is correct, so 2nd is the answer !